# Find a string and copy its whole line to a new file

Tags: string, batch-file, find

how i can copy two lines and not only one ??

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "source=input.txt"
set "target=output.txt"
pushd "%source%"
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /c:"word123" "*.txt"') do (
echo(%%b
)) > "%target%"
popd
```

Input example:

```
aaaaayr
vvvvvyr
9qeieir
qei9i9r
i9iqr9r
word123
s8ru9sr
```

Example Output:

```
i9iqr9r
word123
```

Comment: so if the string has `this line has word123 in it` you want to copy that whole line to a file? What do you mean by 2 lines? and are your lines delimited by `:` in your file? This question is unclear as you did not show input and expected results.

Comment: Also, you set source as `test.txt` but you pushd to it, `test.txt` is not a directory. If it is only test.txt that you want to read from, why do findstr for `*.txt`?

Comment: I mean the two lines near where the word "word123" was found

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50637870/edit) your question, show your INPUT and EXPECTED output.

Comment: Offtopic PowerShell `sls -path .\input.txt -Patt 'word123' -context 1,0|%{$_.Context.PreContext;$_.Line}`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `FindStr` to search across the linebreak:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Src=input.txt"
Set "Dst=output.txt"
Set "Str=word123"

(Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
)
For /F %%A In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" Nul') Do Set "CR=%%A"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Findstr /RC:".*!CR!*!LF!%Str%" /IC:"%Str%" "%Src%">"%Dst%"
EndLocal
```